ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API : returning CSV file wont set file encoding as "Window-1256" encoding
My goal is to return a .CSV file which contains Persian text characters from an ASP.NET Core 8.0 Web API controller action method as a FileContentResult.
I tried the suggested attempts which led me no where.
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Text;

namespace WebApplication.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {

        [HttpGet("attempt1")]
        public IActionResult GetCsv()
        {
            // Sample data with Persian characters
            var csvData = "لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی نامفهوم از صنعت چاپ، و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است .";

            Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            // Get Windows-1256 encoding
            var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256");

            // Encode CSV data in Windows-1256
            var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(csvData);

            // Return the CSV file with proper encoding
            return File(bytes, "text/csv", "persian.csv");
        }

        [HttpGet("attempt2")]
        public IActionResult GetCsv2()
        {
            var csvData = "لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی نامفهوم از صنعت چاپ، و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است .";

            Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1256);

            var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(csvData);

            return File(bytes, "text/csv", "persian.csv");
        }

        [HttpGet("attempt3")]
        public IActionResult GetCsv3()
        {
            var csvData = "لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی نامفهوم از صنعت چاپ، و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است .";


            Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256");

            var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(csvData);

            // Set the content type and charset in the response headers
            Response.Headers.Add("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=persian.csv");
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv; charset=windows-1256";

            return File(bytes, "text/csv", "persian.csv");
        }

        [HttpGet("attempt4")]
        public IActionResult GetCsv4()
        {
            // Sample data with Persian characters
            var csvData = "لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی نامفهوم از صنعت چاپ، و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است .";

            Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            var destEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256");

            var bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.UTF8, destEncoding, Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(csvData));

            return File(bytes, "text/csv", "persian.csv");
        }

        [HttpGet("attempt5")]
        public IActionResult GetCsv5()
        {
            var csvData = "لورم ایپسوم متن ساختگی با تولید سادگی نامفهوم از صنعت چاپ، و با استفاده از طراحان گرافیک است .";

            Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);
            var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256");
            
            // Encode CSV data in Windows-1256 with BOM (if needed)
            var preamble = encoding.GetPreamble(); // Normally, Windows-1256 does not use a BOM, so this will be empty
            var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(csvData);

            // Combine preamble and byte data (normally preamble is empty for Windows-1256)
            var fileContent = new byte[preamble.Length + bytes.Length];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(preamble, 0, fileContent, 0, preamble.Length);
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, fileContent, preamble.Length, bytes.Length);

            // Return the CSV file with proper encoding
            return File(fileContent, "text/csv", "persian.csv");
        } 
    }
}

None of the actions return a .CSV file with readable text, they provide content which illegible text only:

Also if I open the file as "Notepad++" the encoding is set to UTF-8 and not to "Windows-1256" which is my goal:

Info: I'm using .NET 8.0 on Windows 10 OS.

When returning CSV files with Persian characters from your ASP.NET Core Web API, the default encoding might not be Windows-1256.   In order to fix that,  register the encoding provider using Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance), convert the text to bytes using Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1256"), and explicitly set the Content-Disposition and Content-Type headers to include charset=windows-1256. Verify the encoding by downloading the file and checking it in a text editor like Notepad++ to ensure it recognizes the encoding correctly.

Thanks for the reply!!! as I mentioned in question, I tired all of them and did not work.

Hello, thanks for your response, could you please share few more details what exactly didn't work for you, did you get any error or anything? What issue you are currently getting?
